# django - html || for loop issue

Tags: html, django, for-loop, html-table

i want to display all the items from the list 'sum_list' in the html table. but one item get displayed in the table. i know i have to use for loop in html to display all the items and i have tried but failed to do so. i am working with django and below is my views.py code in which sum_list is defined.

```
    detail = Sale_detail()
    sum_list= []
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = x.strftime("%B")
    path = r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\Sale detail sheet\SALE DETAIL SHEET JANUARY 2020.xlsx'
    customers1 = [20,31,28,27,17,46,13,15,14,37,100125,100051,100062,100087,100072,100071,100070,100057,100056,100066,100068,100086,100091,100103,100126,100131,100145,100150,100152,100140,100165,100180]
    customers2 = [ 'Asian Cements','Asian Fine', 'UTCL Roorkee', 'UTCL Bagheri','UTCL Panipat','UTCL Sikandrabad','Ambuja Nalagargh','Ambuja Ropar','Ambuja Roorkee','Ambuja Dadri','ACC LTD','Fateh','Everest','Hemkund Sahib','Rakesh kumar','Amritsaria','Jai Shiv shankar','Ramjee','Paras','Manju','Sachin','R.S.Green','BTS','S.A.Bricks','Royal','M.M. Concrete','Fairmont','Aniket','A One','ONS','NTC','Guru Teg Bhadar']
    customers2_length = range(0,len(customers2))
    today = date.today()
    d1 = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    tarik = d1   
    df = pd.read_excel(open(path,"rb"),sheet_name= month.upper(), index_col=None, header=  None)
    for (i,j) in zip(customers1, customers2_length):
        ab = df[df[2] == i]
        a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
        b = round(a,2)
        i = customers2[j]
        if b != 0:
            sum_list.append([i, str(b)])
    # print(sum_list)

    for i,j in sum_list:
        detail.customer = i
        detail.qty = j
    return render(request,'index.html', {'x': detail})
```

and this my html part to display item in shape of table

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Customer</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity (MT)</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>


        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>{{x.customer}}</td>
        <td>{{x.qty}}</td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

please help me in solving this to view all the items from the list in table.

Comment: You are sending a single `Sale_detail` object in your `context`. Is this your desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The stuff with detail in views.py is unnecessary.
Rather, construct your list with

```
sum_list.append( (i, str(b)) )
```

and do render `{'sum_list': sum_list}` 
and then in your template, inside the body of your table:

```
 {% for x, y in sum_list %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ x }}</td>
        <td>{{ y }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this one worked flawless. thanks for the help. one more thing i want to know that how to get the table refreshed automatically as a new entry gets created. currently i have to refresh the page to consider the new entries.

Comment: Hum ! refreshing the page when an entry is added is quite another question. I cannot answer this one, sorry !